# Split comma separated key-value pairs which has comma in value

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string that has key-value pair as comma-separated and I want to split the string into key-value. I have a problem in splitting if the value has a comma.

Below is the sample string

```
job=123,Auto=Workflow1,Workflow2,debug=true
```

and I want to split the above string into key-value as below

```
job=123
Auto=Workflow1,Workflow2
debug=true
```

How can I do this?

Comment: That's not scv. *Fields with embedded commas or double-quote characters must be quoted* ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values#Basic_rules)). So idea of parsing this string with scv library is wrong.

Comment: What if the value has an equal symbol?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can try splitting on the following regex pattern:

```regex
,(?=[^,]+=)
```

This will match any comma for which we can find an `=` following *without* crossing over another comma.  This rules out the in between commas which we don't want to split.

Sample code:

```
string input = "job=123,Auto=Workflow1,Workflow2,debug=true";
string[] parts = Regex.Split(input, @",(?=[^,]+=)");
foreach (string part in parts)
Console.WriteLine(part);
```

This prints:

```
job=123
Auto=Workflow1,Workflow2
debug=true
```

Comment: As much as I try to avoid regex, I would support and use this.